# Is it possible to merge a branch in git and preserve the history?

Tags: git, git-svn

I use git-svn to interface with our Subversion repository at work. I created a branch (let's call it FeatureBranch) to work on a new feature, but had to switch back to the master branch to work on something else. When I began work on what was supposed to be done on FeatureBranch, I forgot to check out FeatureBranch again and made several commits to the master branch before realizing what I had done.

I had originally planned on doing the following to fix this (I have not yet dcommitted my changes to Subversion, so they are all grouped together as the most recent commits I've made):

```
git checkout FeatureBranch
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~n
```

where *n* is the number of commits I want to remove from the master branch since they would be in FeatureBranch now. However, *git merge* does not seem to retain history when merging to another branch (it shows as a single commit). How do you merge only certain commits in git to another branch, while retaining history? I've heard the term *cherry-pick* before, is this the functionality I should be looking into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would want to use git cherry-pick for this. You will quite literally *cherry pick* each commit you want to bring back to the master.

Without explaining the entire cherry-pick process, here are some [Docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) that will [get](http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick) you [started](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHn-0Md9sXo)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out. I'm always wary of trying new things with Git-Svn before confirming if they'll work

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks. Thankfully there were only about 8 commits I needed to fix, any more and I'd have been more mad at myself (very tedious!)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `git rebase --onto`. see `git help rebase` for details.